# Nesting of different loops in C

Tags: c, loops

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int num,incentive;
    int salary=1500;
    float w_hr, avg_time,LOP,tot_sal;
    int tot_hr=50;
    printf("Enter the no. of projects allocated\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("Enter the no. of working hours\n");
    scanf("%f",&w_hr);
    if(num<=10)
    {
        if(w_hr<tot_hr)
        {
            avg_time=w_hr/num;
            printf("Average Time Taken(Hrs)\n%f",avg_time);
        }
        else if(w_hr>50&&w_hr<=55)
        {
            LOP=0.5;
            tot_sal=(((100-LOP)/100)*salary);
            printf("You have exceeded the timeline\n");
            printf("Your Salary is Rs.%.2f",tot_sal);
        }
        else if(w_hr>55&&w_hr<=60)
        {
            LOP=1.0;
            tot_sal=(((100-LOP)/100)*salary);
            printf("You have exceeded the timeline\n");
            printf("You Salary is Rs.%.2f",tot_sal);
        }
        else if(w_hr>60&&w_hr<=70)
        {
            LOP=1.5;
            tot_sal=(((100-LOP)/100)*salary);
            printf("You have exceeded the timeline\n");
            printf("Your Salary is Rs.%.2f",tot_sal);
        }
        else
        printf("Invalid input");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The maximum limit on project count has been specified as %d. SORRY!!",num);
    }
    while(w_hr<tot_hr)
    {
        if(avg_time<5)
        {
        incentive=5000;
        tot_sal=salary+incentive;
        printf("Your Salary is %.f",tot_sal);
        }
        else if(avg_time>=5&&avg_time<7)
        {
            incentive=2000;
            tot_sal=salary+incentive;
            printf("Your Salary is %.f",tot_sal);
        }
        else if(avg_time>=7&&avg_time<10)
        {
            incentive=1500;
            tot_sal=salary+incentive;
            printf("Your Salary is %.f",tot_sal);
        }
        else
        {
            incentive=500;
            tot_sal=salary+incentive;
            print("Your Salary is %.f",tot_sal);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above program, the following error appears,

```
calculatesalary.c:44: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘else’
     else
     ^
calculatesalary.c:48: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘while’
     while(w_hr<tot_hr)
     ^
calculatesalary.c:75: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^
```

I've got an error in the else part and the while loop stating that an identifier or `(` before `}`,`while` and `else` token is expected.

Is there any mistake in the way the loops are nested?

Code's question:-

Ragav, an accounts manager works in Abil Solutions. One day he decided to modify the way for calculating the salary for the employees who are handling projects in his organization. He has to maintain the salary details with respect to the projects done by the employees within the time line. The total number of hours to complete the work allocated is 50. The employees can handle maximum of 10 projects at the same time. The employees should not go beyond the time line. If an employee takes more time than the time period he will be provided with Loss of Pay from his salary. If he completes the project with low average time he will get incentive. The salary for the complete project is Rs.1500/-

If the time taken is greater than 50 hours calculate salary with loss of pay, not necessary to calculate average time. The average time taken has to be in float type.

Average Time/project(Hrs)               Incentive(Rs.)

below 5                                             5000

> =5 and <7                                       2000
>
> =7 and <10                                     1500
>
> =10                                                  500

Time Taken (Hrs)                             Loss of Pay(%)

> 50 and <=55                                  0.5
>
> 55 and <=60                                  1.0
>
> 60 and <=70                                  1.5
>
> 70                                                  Invalid Input

Test Case

Input 1

Enter the no.of projects allocated

5

Enter the no.of working hours

30

Output 1

Average Time Taken (Hrs)

6.0

Your Salary is Rs.9500

Input 2

Enter the no.of projects allocated

8

Enter the no.of working hours

55

Output 2

You have exceeded the timeline.

Your Salary is Rs.11940

Input 3

Enter the no.of projects allocated

12

Enter the no.of working hours

40

Output 3

The maximum limit on project count has been specified as 10. Sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra `}` after the else statement in line 46. After correcting it, code will be

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num,incentive;
    int salary=1500;
    float w_hr, avg_time,LOP,tot_sal;
    int tot_hr=50;
    printf("Enter the no. of projects allocated\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("Enter the no. of working hours\n");
    scanf("%f",&w_hr);
    if(num<=10)
    {
        if(w_hr<tot_hr)
        {
            avg_time=w_hr/num;
            printf("Average Time Taken(Hrs)\n%f",avg_time);
        }
        else if(w_hr>50&&w_hr<=55)
        {
            LOP=0.5;
            tot_sal=(((100-LOP)/100)*salary);
            printf("You have exceeded the timeline\n");
            printf("Your Salary is Rs.%.2f",tot_sal);
        }
        else if(w_hr>55&&w_hr<=60)
        {
            LOP=1.0;
            tot_sal=(((100-LOP)/100)*salary);
            printf("You have exceeded the timeline\n");
            printf("You Salary is Rs.%.2f",tot_sal);
        }
        else if(w_hr>60&&w_hr<=70)
        {
            LOP=1.5;
            tot_sal=(((100-LOP)/100)*salary);
            printf("You have exceeded the timeline\n");
            printf("Your Salary is Rs.%.2f",tot_sal);
        }
        else
            printf("Invalid input");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The maximum limit on project count has been specified as %d. SORRY!!",num);
    }
    while(w_hr<tot_hr)
    {
        if(avg_time<5)
        {
        incentive=5000;
        tot_sal=salary+incentive;
        printf("Your Salary is %.f",tot_sal);
        }
        else if(avg_time>=5&&avg_time<7)
        {
            incentive=2000;
            tot_sal=salary+incentive;
            printf("Your Salary is %.f",tot_sal);
        }
        else if(avg_time>=7&&avg_time<10)
        {
            incentive=1500;
            tot_sal=salary+incentive;
            printf("Your Salary is %.f",tot_sal);
        }
        else
        {
            incentive=500;
            tot_sal=salary+incentive;
            printf("Your Salary is %.f",tot_sal);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is creating a problem. I have made the required corrections:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num,incentive;
    int salary=1500;
    float w_hr, avg_time,LOP,tot_sal;
    int tot_hr=50;

    printf("Enter the no.of projects allocated\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    printf("Enter the no.of working hours\n");
    scanf("%f",&w_hr);
    if(num<=10){
        if(w_hr<tot_hr){
            avg_time=w_hr/num;
            printf("Average Time Taken (Hrs)\n%.1f",avg_time);

            if(avg_time<5.0){
                incentive=5000;
                tot_sal=salary*num+incentive;
                printf("\nYour Salary is Rs.%.f",tot_sal);                
            }
            else if(avg_time>=5.0 && avg_time<7.0){
                incentive=2000;
                tot_sal=salary*num+incentive;
                printf("\nYour Salary is Rs.%.f",tot_sal);
            }
            else if(avg_time>=7.0 && avg_time<10.0){
                incentive=1500;
                tot_sal=salary*num+incentive;
                printf("\nYour Salary is Rs.%.f",tot_sal);
            }
            else{
                incentive=500;
                tot_sal=salary*num+incentive;
                printf("\nYour Salary is Rs.%.f",tot_sal);
            }
        }
        else if(w_hr>50&&w_hr<=55){
            LOP=0.5;
            tot_sal=num*(((100-LOP)/100)*salary);
            printf("You have exceeded the timeline\n");
            printf("\nYour Salary is Rs.%.f",tot_sal);
        }
        else if(w_hr>55&&w_hr<=60){
            LOP=1.0;
            tot_sal=(((100-LOP)/100)*salary);
            printf("You have exceeded the timeline\n");
            printf("\nYour Salary is Rs.%.2f",tot_sal);
        }
        else if(w_hr>60&&w_hr<=70){
            LOP=1.5;
            tot_sal=(((100-LOP)/100)*salary);
            printf("You have exceeded the timeline\n");
            printf("\nYour Salary is Rs.%.2f",tot_sal);
        }
        else
            printf("\nInvalid input");
        }
    else{
        printf("The maximum limit on project count has been specified as 10. Sorry!!");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should add some description of your changes so it's clear what was the issue.